# matplotlib.pyplot, keep same scale for multiple labels on Y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I need to be able to write code that can easily graph data points. There is a single x axis, and there are multiple columns that represent the points on the y axis. All of the data points on the y axis should be part of the same scale (between 0, and 5,000, for example). matplotlib is not doing this, and all I can find when I do research is how to plot data points using different y axis scales (which is exactly what I'm not wanting).
[In this particular picture, I'm not really sure what the y-axis is doing. In the original data, the points go from 0, to about 4,000,000, and also include numbers very close to 0 (10^-11).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0v1a.png)

Either way, I want it to start 0 and then scale itself up to 4,000,000 (or whatever the highest value is). It looks like it's going form 0 to 2,0000 back to very close to zero.

Here is another example of an issue that I'm having:
[In this particular plot, it looks like the blue label is tailing off of the rest of the plot. It's in the same range as the rest of the points, except that the maximum value is 1526 instead of 1527. Additionally, it looks like the scale keeps resetting to accommodate other labels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G6o1.png)

Ideally, for the second set of plots, I want the scale to go from 0 to 1527. I want all of the data points plotted along the same axis, instead of having different scales crammed into one axis. I just have no clue how to do this. I don't see this sort of thing being addressed in the documentation either.

I'll add the code that I use in order to make the plot:

```
for graph in graphs:
xaxis = graph.data_dict['xaxis']
# Go through each column (except for xaxis) and plot
for column in (i for i in graph.data_dict if i != 'xaxis'):
    # Get the data for the column
    y = graph.data_dict[column]
    # Plot it
    plt.plot(xaxis,y)
    plt.yticks(fontsize="small")
# xaxis is the x label
plt.xticks(fontsize="small")
# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: It appears that you are plotting numeric data as strings, which is not correct.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney You're right, that was it. After I converted the data into a numeric type, matplotlib was able to figure out the rest. Thanks!